# How to parseInt with character prefix

Tags: javascript, parseint

This returns NaN because of the euro-sign in front of it.

```
parseInt('€ 213,-');
```

How do I get the integer inside, is there a nicer way than first removing the first character?

Comment: You are talking about integer, but euros can have cents. Is that comma your decimals separator?

Answer (score 4):

You should replace the string first

```
var str = '€ 213,-'.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,"");
parseInt(str); // sometimes int won't be good because of decimal
var money = Number(str); // use Number instead
```

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expressions...

```
parseInt('€ 213,-'.match( /\d+/g ));
```